# How to compress javascript code in Base62 encoding without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, compression, base64, eval

I used [this javascript compressor](http://www.javascriptcompressor.com/) and checked "Base62 Encode". I noticed that the very first thing it does is enclose everything in an `eval()` function (which makes sense) but I *really* want to avoid using it. Is there any alternative?? Like an immediately invoked function expression?

#### Edit:

I want to compress my code because there's a ton of conditional `if`s for feature detection. (The reason I'm not using Modernizr is because I
don't want to load a whole library for just what I'm doing), and the `if`s are ugly. (Plus I'm new to javascript and I'd rather learn javascript
    than learn Modernizr).

Comment: This looks like one of those cases where `eval` is appropriate. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Well, it's not a huge deal, but I just would rather not do it. It's ugly and outdated, plus, in some cases, anti-virus software may be suspicious of it. I went to a blog post about `eval()` and my firewall warned me, but with my firewall turned off, it was fine.

Comment: Do you really want to obfuscate your code? If not, you could use another kind of compressor to minify the code, like http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: I'm not too concerned with obfuscating my code, no. But the code I want to compress is a bunch of `if` statements, so even with normal compression, it still looks massive. So, on second though, yes. I want to obfuscate my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace eval(...) with new Function(...)() like so:

```
new Function(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('2(a.6){3.4("5")[0].1+=" 6"}2(b.7){3.4("5")[0].1+=" 7"}2(8.9){3.4("5")[0].1+=" 9"}2(8.c){3.4("5")[0].1+=" d"}',14,14,'|className|if|document|getElementsByTagName|html|opacity|touch|html5|webworkers|css3|has|audio|html5audio'.split('|'),0,{}))()
```

It's not really much of an improvement but it avoids using eval.

Answer (score 0):

On first inspection, [Closure Compile](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) doesn't wrap your code in an `eval()` call. [Here's a tutorial](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui) on using the GUI version.